# I have a mutual recursion problem in f-sharp

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I have the following types in F#:

```
type Name = string;;
type Sex = 
    | M // male
    | F // female
type YearOfBirth = int;;
type FamilyTree = P of Name * Sex * YearOfBirth * Children
and Children = FamilyTree list;;

//here is an example:
let f1 = P("Larry",M,1920,[P("May",F,1945,[P("Fred",M,1970,[])]);P("Joe",M,1950,[P("Adam",M,1970,[])]);P("Paul",M,1955,[])])
```

My task is to create a function: find: Name -> FamilyTree -> returns (found name, sex, year, [List of the names of all their children]

I know it has something to do with mutual recursion but I am not sure how to apply it.
This is what I wrote so far:

```
let fstn (f:FamilyTree) =
    match f with
    |P(n,s,y,c) -> n

let rec find n t = function
    |P(n1,s1,y1,cs) -> if n1=n then (n1,s1,y1,List.map (fun x -> fstn x) cs) 
                           else findC n cs
and findC n clist =
    match clist with
    |[] -> []
    |c::cs -> if n = fstn c then find n c 
                            else findC n cs
```

When I run

```
find "May" f1;;
```

I get:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'Name * Sex * YearOfBirth * Name list'
but here has type
    ''a list'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I know there is a problem with types but I am not sure how to fix it. I could use all the help I could get, thank you very much!

Comment: If you type annotate all of your functions it'll be easy to figure it out.

Comment: To start with the function find expects two parameters but then the implementation expects only one (FamilyTree).

Comment: General tip: It often helps to have an accompanying [catamorphism](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds/) for recursive types. In your code, a catamorphism can easily match the current node's name with the request and return an option, which will signal parent nodes to stop the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution runs in Visual Studio Pro 2019, Version 16.8.3...

```
// addressing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307389/i-have-a-mutual-recursion-problem-in-f-sharp

open System

type Name = string
type Sex = 
    | M // male
    | F // female
type YearOfBirth = int;;
type FamilyTree = 
    | Person of Name * Sex * YearOfBirth * Children
    | Nothing 
and 
    Children = FamilyTree list

//here is an example:
let family_example = [Person("Larry",M,1920,
                        [Person("May",F,1945,
                            [Person("Fred",M,1970,[])]);
                             Person("Joe",M,1950,
                                [Person("Adam",M,1970,[])]);
                             Person("Paul",M,1955,[])
                             ]
                         )]

let rec find name ( familyTree_list : FamilyTree list) : FamilyTree =
    match familyTree_list with
    | (Person( try_name, _, _, _)::_) & (person::_) when name = try_name -> person 
    | (Person( _, _, _, children)::siblings) when (children <> [] || siblings <> []) ->
        let depth_search_result = find name children
        if Nothing <> depth_search_result then depth_search_result
        else find name siblings
    | _ -> Nothing

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%A" (find "May" family_example)
    printfn "%A" (find "Joe" family_example)
    printfn "%A" (find "no one" family_example)
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The variable and type names are were made readable but are mostly the same from your version.  Functions `fstn` and `findC` were not needed.  `f1` became `family_example` and was reformatted for readability.

You can pull down a git repo of this solution from [FSharpAnswers_by_RFreytag](https://github.com/rfreytag/FSharpAnswers_by_RFreytag/branches), branch `StackOverflow_001_I_have_a_mutual_recursion_problem_in_f-sharp`.

Let me know if you have any further questions.